# How to bypass "MACHINE LEARNING" malware detection on a not malicious software?

Tags: c#

So I made a simple login app in c# as a fun project and I wanted to test it but I icant somehow

```
namespace DeathNote
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text=="Extra" && txtpassword.Text=="test")
            {
                new Form2().Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The username or password is incorrect!");
                txtUserName.Clear();
                txtpassword.Clear();
                txtUserName.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtpassword.Clear();
            txtUserName.Clear();
            txtUserName.Focus();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand why I get this: the malware is obviously triggered by something and I think its exit button but im not sure.

Any way to bypass it or a way to code it more efficiently?

[image: malware warning]

Comment: Can't you add an exclusion to Malwarebytes? Optionally report it to the Malwarebytes' support.

Comment: ye but I want to send it to my friend as he is suspicious of me now -

Comment: And he would be less suspicious knowing you are trying to "bypass his anti-malware"? This seems like a typical false positive in Malwarebytes. I'm not sure you'll be able to find anyone here on SO who can tell you what triggers it, which is why I suggest reporting it to their support.

Comment: Ref: https://blog.malwarebytes.com/detections/machinelearning-anomalous-100/